# Accessing to picklist value in a specific language

Tags: apex, visualforce, translation

i'm facing a problem : i need to access to translated values of a picklist thanks to Apex.

I have a picklist with English master values and i have translated these values thanks to the Translation Workbench.

I'm using a public site with Visualforce Page and the anonymous user seems to be french. I have added the language parameter in all page in order to translate pages thanks to a parameter but when i use the Describe function in my Apex Class, the getLabel() of PicklistEntry retrieved the french values instead of the language page.

Is-there a solution or does i need to create a Custom Setting in order to map master value to all the translated values ?